# Conditional aggregation Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to understand the best way to do an aggregation in Spark in this scenario:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._  
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
case class Person(name:String, acc:Int, logDate:String)
val dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
val filterType = // Could has "MIN" or "MAX" depending on a run parameter
val filterDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis)

val df = sc.parallelize(List(Person("Giorgio",20,"31/12/9999"),
                             Person("Giorgio",30,"12/10/2009")
                             Person("Diego",  10,"12/10/2010"),
                             Person("Diego",  20,"12/10/2010"),
                             Person("Diego",  30,"22/11/2011"), 
                             Person("Giorgio",10,"31/12/9999"),
                             Person("Giorgio",30,"31/12/9999"))).toDF()

val df2 = df.withColumn("logDate",unix_timestamp($"logDate",dateFormat).cast(TimestampType))

val df3 = df.groupBy("name").agg(/*conditional aggregation*/)
df3.show /*Expected output show  below */
```

Basically I want to group all records by `name` column and then based on the `filterType` parameter, I want to filter all valid records for a Person, then after filtering, I want to sum all `acc` values obtaining a final
`DataFrame` with **name** and **totalAcc** columns.

For example:

- filterType = **MIN** , I want to take all records with having min(logDate) , could be many of them, so basically in this case I completely ignore filterDate param:

`Diego,10,12/10/2010
 Diego,20,12/10/2010
 Giorgio,30,12/10/2009`

Final result expected from aggregation is: **(Diego, 30),(Giorgio,30)**

- filterType = **MAX** , I want to take all records with logDate > filterDate, I for a key I don't have any records respecting this condition, I need to take records with min(logDate) as done in MIN scenario, so:

`Diego,   10, 12/10/2010
 Diego,   20, 12/10/2010
 Giorgio, 20, 31/12/9999
 Giorgio, 10, 31/12/9999
 Giorgio, 30, 31/12/9999`

Final result expected from aggregation is: **(Diego,30),(Giorgio,60)**
In this case for Diego I didn't have any records with logDate > logFilter, so I fallback to apply MIN scenario, taking just for Diego all records with min logDate.

Comment: what if you have two records of Diego both smaller than filterDate? can you clarify what would be the output

Comment: If for Diego I have just records smaller than logDate, for flowType MIN I Will take the records with min logDate, if both of them has min logDate, I'll sum them. For MAX scenario if for Diego I don't have any records with logDate >logfilter, then I will look for records with min logDate exactly as done for MIN scenario

Comment: I updated again also for the scenario you mentioned before.

Comment: The record   of 2011 for Diego must be excluded from both scenario because for MIN It doesn't min logDate and for MAX scenario It fails  logDate > logFilter

Comment: I have updated my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your conditional aggregation using `when/otherwise` as

```
df2.groupBy("name").agg(sum(when(lit(filterType) === "MIN" && $"logDate" < filterDate, $"acc").otherwise(when(lit(filterType) === "MAX" && $"logDate" > filterDate, $"acc"))).as("sum"))
    .filter($"sum".isNotNull)
```

which would give you your desired output according to `filterType`

But

*Eventually you would require both aggregated dataframes* so I would suggest you to avoid `filterType` field and just go with aggregation by *creating additional column for grouping* using `when/otherwise` function. So that you can have both aggregated values in one dataframe as

```
df2.withColumn("additionalGrouping", when($"logDate" < filterDate, "less").otherwise("more"))
    .groupBy("name", "additionalGrouping").agg(sum($"acc"))
    .drop("additionalGrouping")
    .show(false)
```

which would output as

```
+-------+--------+
|name   |sum(acc)|
+-------+--------+
|Diego  |10      |
|Giorgio|60      |
+-------+--------+
```

## Updated

Since the question is updated with the logic changed, here is the idea and solution to the changed scenario

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy($"logDate".asc)

val minDF = df2.withColumn("minLogDate", first("logDate").over(windowSpec)).filter($"minLogDate" === $"logDate")
  .groupBy("name")
  .agg(sum($"acc").as("sum"))

val finalDF =
  if(filterType == "MIN") {
    minDF
  }
  else if(filterType == "MAX"){
    val tempMaxDF = df2
      .groupBy("name")
      .agg(sum(when($"logDate" > filterDate,$"acc")).as("sum"))

    tempMaxDF.filter($"sum".isNull).drop("sum").join(minDF, Seq("name"), "left").union(tempMaxDF.filter($"sum".isNotNull))
  }
  else {
    df2
  }
```

so for `filterType = MIN` you should have

```
+-------+---+
|name   |sum|
+-------+---+
|Diego  |30 |
|Giorgio|30 |
+-------+---+
```

and for `filterType = MAX` you should have

```
+-------+---+
|name   |sum|
+-------+---+
|Diego  |30 |
|Giorgio|60 |
+-------+---+
```

In case if the `filterType` isn't `MAX` or `MIN` then original dataframe is returned

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Why did you choose implementing the solution using Windowing function? It give you some kind of performance boost or what else ?

Comment: Thats mainly because there was a need for computation within a group and output all the rows and window function is best for that. Do you have anything else in mind? @Giorgio

Comment: I'm quite newbie with DataFrame, maybe you can help me to clarify the following point: I'm thinking about in terms of performance, because actually in production I will face with a DataFrame of 30-35 milions of records and I would asking myself if the window and the join in case of MAX filterType could a bottleneck.

Comment: well your requirement suggests that you need to identify the minimum within a group thats why a window function and your second max requirement suggests that you need both minimum and max so a join. You can alway search for best alternatives . But the solution I presented is the best solution I know of. If you find better option than this please do let me know by answering . and if not you are always welcome to upvote and accept the answer. thanks

Comment: I wasn't be something like polemic. I just want to share with you my doubts because you seems very expert. I just asking myself if for you in terms of performance could be best do all computations in one dataFrame (if possible, maybe using the your first solution and adapt it in the new scenario) or do more DataFrame joining them. Thanks

Comment: the MIN requirement is straight forward and is complete in one dataframe but your MAX requirement has `I didn't have any records with logDate > logFilter, so I fallback to apply MIN scenario, taking just for Diego all records with min logDate.` which needs to check through whole dataframe for checking if a record doesn't meet MAX condition, if it doesn;t then you need to apply MIN condition on the records which doesn't meet MAX condition. so since MIN logic is already impemented and calculated why not use it for MAX condition using join. thats the logic I used

Comment: last question: for the sake of performance, in order to accomplish my scenario, it will be better to pass to RDD or use DataFrame with Window function as you explained me? Regards

Comment: Dataframes are optimized forms of rdd. optimized for both speed and memory usage. but if you have faster options in rdd you can always use that. Test and confirm. Thanks

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Hi thanks for the answer. Just one question, if i do filter first then aggregation like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018384/8932910), what do you think of the performance difference? What's the benefit of using conditional aggregation inside `.agg(sum(when(...`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need conditional aggregation. Just filter:

```
df
  .where(if (filterType == "MAX") $"logDate" < filterDate else $"logDate" > filterDate)
  .groupBy("name").agg(sum($"acc")
```